# regex for separate links inside of paragrahps

Tags: angular, regex, url

I have the following string

> `<p>www.test.com</p><p><br></p><p>https://cust-portal-v2-ciuk-uk.javelin.g4s.com/dashb</p><p>www.link.com</p>`

I want to urlize it using a regex

> const regex = (?:(?:https?://)|(?:www.))[^\s]+

What I expect is to have 3 matches, instead of a single one

[image]

How can I alter the regex to find each link? And also without the closing tag of the paragraph

> `</p>`

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```js
const regex = /<p>([^<]*)<\/p>/g;
const data = '<p>www.test.com</p><p><br></p><p>https://cust-portal-v2-ciuk-uk.javelin.g4s.com/dashb</p><p>www.link.com</p>';

const results = [];
while(res = regex.exec(data)) results.push(res[1]);
console.log(results);
```

The regex says

> Take everyting between paragrpah tags, which are not opening tags "<".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way that comes to my mind:

```
\b(?:http:\/\/|www.|https:\/\/)[\/a-z0-9.-]+
```

I didn't add the whole possible characters you can encounter in a URL but well, for the example you provided it should work nicely.

[image: result]